# Probability of winning a simple game

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

> Consider two players, A and B start with 8 and 6 stones respectively. A rolls a six-sided die to determine how many stones to take from B. B performs the same task to determine how many stones to take from A. Whoever has the most stones wins. If A and B have equal stones they play another round. What is the probability B will win after 1,2,..,n rounds?

Let a1 = number of stones A wins and b1 = number of stones b wins then the probability of B winning the first round is:

$$P(8 + A1 - B1 < 6 + B1 - A1) = P(2 < 2(B1 - A1))$$

I know that A1 and B1 follow a discrete uniform $f(x) = \frac{1}{6}$ but I am not sure how to proceed. Normally I would multiply the MGF's to derive the distribution, take the inverse of the problem and calculate the cmf.

Comment: Once (if) they end up having equal stones after round one, each subsequent round will be fair and will have the same probability of ending in another draw. So you need P(first round ending in a draw)*P(a fair round ending in a draw)^(n-2)*P(B winning a fair round)

If I understood it correctly

Comment: @grdgfgr: This is pretty close to a full answer. It may be a good idea to write an answer, so that the question will not remain unanswered.

Answer (score 0):

Once (if) they end up having equal stones after round one, each subsequent round will be fair and will have the same probability of ending in another draw.

So you need:
$$P(first\ round\ ending\ in\ a\ draw)\times P(a\ fair\ round\ ending\ in\ a\ draw)^{n-2}\\\times P(B\ winning\ a\ fair\ round)$$